# Powershell copy file from an environment variable to the zip folder of another environment variable

Tags: powershell, zip, azure-pipelines

I am really new to the Powershell and want to copy a file from BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY environment variable to a zip folder inside BUILD_STAGINGDIRECTORY environment variable in my VSTS build definition.

```
if(Test-Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY/MyFolder/MyFIle.txt)
{
 Write-Host "Source File: $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY/MyFolder/MyFIle.txt"
 Write-Host "Target Location: $Env:BUILD_STAGINGDIRECTORY\StagingDirectoryFolder.zip\TestFolder"
}
```

Copy file from one path to another is quite straight forward but I really don't know how to move file into the zip folder structure.

Comment: What is the version of PowerShell and .NET Framework? While Windows Explorer/File Explorer can treat .zip files as though they were integrated into the file system, PowerShell cannot. Some versions of the .NET Framework have object classes that can be used to manipulate .zip files, but older versions do not.

Comment: Powershell Version: 5,
DotNetFramework: 4

Comment: PS 5 or 5.1? .NET 4, 4.5, 4.6.*, 4.7? You should paste the output of `$psversiontable` into your question.

Comment: PS 5.1, and I can see the following 
DotNetFrameworks in my agent capabilities DotNetFramework C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework_4.7.0 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework_4.7.0_x64 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

Comment: You need to extract the zip; move the file in to the unzipped folder; then zip it back up again. Look at `Expand-Archive` and `Compress-Archive`

Comment: @gvee is correct - you should look at the [`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1) and [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlets; your PowerShell and .net are both recent enough to support them.

Comment: Can i store the Expand-Archive result into a variable. If yes, can you please give me an example or it has to be at some physical path?

Comment: Let's take a step back: What is generating the zip archive in the first place? Why do you want to put a file in it *after* it's created?

Comment: Thanks @gvee. Expand-Archive and Compress-Archive had done the job for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy `MyFIle.txt` to the subfolder `TestFolder` under a zip file by `Expand-Archive` and `Compress-Archive` (as gvee mentions). The PowerShell script as below:

```
if(Test-Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyFolder/MyFIle.txt)
{
  clear-host
  [string]$zipF = '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\StagingDirectoryFolder.zip'
  [string]$fileToZip = '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyFolder\MyFIle.txt'
  [string]$tempEx= '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\temp'
  [string]$copyDes='$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\temp\TestFolder'
  Expand-Archive -Path $zipF -DestinationPath $tempEx -Force
  Copy-Item $fileToZip -Destination $copyDes -Force
  Compress-Archive -Path $tempEx\* -Update -DestinationPath $zipF 
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $tempEx
}
```

Now the zip file `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\StagingDirectoryFolder.zip` contains `MyFIle.txt` under `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\StagingDirectoryFolder.zip\TestFolder`.

Comment: I have followed a similar approach to get it done. Tried to follow the variable approach as u did but for some reason it didn't work. It run script file (.ps1) without an error but don't do anything. Replacing variables with my old approach of direct paths, it works really well. Have marked your answer!.

Comment: My mistake @Marina. Your answer is spot on. I was making the mistake of assigning $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY and $Env:BUILD_STAGINGDIRECTORY to my variables rather $(Build.SourcesDirectory) and $(Build.StagingDirectory). It is really strange though, Powershell accept $Env:SOURCESDIRECTORY when provided directly but complains when provide the same through variable.

Answer (score 1):

If I could suggest a non power shell solution (although it is worth looking up the [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1) and [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlets as recommended in the comments.)

I would use a `Archive Files` build task to handle the zipping. In your power shell build script, copy your artifact(s) into `$ENV:BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY`, and then leverage the VSTS build to do the archiving of all of the files.

[image: archive step]

This then lets you publish that zip file using the VSTS build which will allow it to be easily accessible through the VSTS web gui which imo offers a superior user experience (for troubleshooting your build, as well as other users who need access to those artifacts (either physical people, or automated processes)). If you need to do something else with the zip file, you could then add another powershell script after your `archive files` that would be able to access the file from the `$ENV:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY`. This way your scripts stay simple, and you can offload some of your build maintenance onto Microsoft.